# JAVA: How to start several threads in 1 class

Tags: java, multithreading

In java for starting a single thread, class should implement it's run method

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {
    run() {
        // some stuff
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

The question is what should I do if I need to start several different threads in my class. I know 1 way to do that - implement class for every thread function, but I think there should be more simple way.

Comment: can u explain why u want to start many threads that doesnt sound like to have any purpose.

Comment: You should take a look to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: we start a new thread to do a logic. if u need to do several unrelated logic, you should have to implement several threads

Comment: this won't even compile... You can't use 'this' in static method

Answer (score 2):

This code creates and starts four threads:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {
    run() {
        // some stuff
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(myClass);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(myClass);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(myClass);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(myClass);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a different instance of `MyClass` for each `Thread`?

Comment: To have a sync across all the threads, all threads must belong to the same object. If you create threads using different objects then they will not be in sync.

Comment: You can use same instance. But you should be careful if you modify fields of this instance from multiple threads

Comment: @IvanM That is why I mentioned it, but to have some sync this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your thread class as below.

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable{  
public MyClass(){}  
public void run(){  
// some operation here  
}  
}
```

in your MainClass you can start as many thread as :

```
   MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();  
    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();  
    Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1);  
    Thread t2 = new Thread(obj2);  
    t1.start();  
    t2.start();
```